# How to sort when also using a where clause

Tags: database, list, linq, sorting, where-clause

I am currently pulling a list from a database, using the following code. The list is retrieved using a WHERE condition, however the list is returned unsorted. This is in the controller.

How can I modify this code so that the returned list is sorted alphabetically?

```
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TargetYear))
        {
            ViewBag.HSID = new SelectList(db.Hotspots.Where(g => g.HSID.Contains(TargetYear)).ToList(), "ID", "HSID");
        }
```

On several other fields I have used the following method to order, but I'm not sure how, or if I can combine this with the where clause above. The key piece is ".OrderBy(e=>e.FIELD), however this is precisely the piece I'm not sure how to integrate with the query.

```
ViewBag.LocalityCode = new SelectList(db.Localities.OrderBy(e=>e.LOCALITY1), "LOC_CODE", "LOCALITY1");
```

Other helpful bits of info:

ASP.Net MVC5

Microsoft SQL 2012

Comment: call the orderby after the where `Where(...).OrderBy(...)`

Comment: ` ViewBag.HSID = new SelectList(db.Hotspots.Where(g => g.HSID.Contains(TargetYear)).OrderBy(e=>e.HSID).ToList(), "ID", "HSID");`

I didn't realise I could stack things like that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(TargetYear))
    {
        var data = 
         db.Hotspots
           .Where(g => g.HSID.Contains(TargetYear))
           .OrderBy(e=>e.HSID)
           .ToList();
        ViewBag.HSID = new SelectList(data,"ID", "HSID");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great